# Properly Importing Nested Modules and Dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript

Ok here is the problem. I have a parent module that imports shared components that I want to share with nested modules within the parent module.  The parent module looks like this:

### Shared Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TableComponent } from './forms/table/table.component';
import { RadioComponent } from './forms/radio/radio.component';
import { InputComponent } from './forms/input/input.component';
import { BrandingModule } from "./branding/branding.module";
import { RowComponent } from './grid/row/row.component';
import { ColumnComponent } from './grid/column/column.component';
import { TilesComponent } from './grid/tiles/tiles.component';
import { CTAComponent } from "./cta/cta.component";
import { ModalComponent } from "./modal/modal.component";
import { TextHeaderComponent } from "./text-header/text-header.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrandingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    TableComponent, 
    RadioComponent,
    InputComponent,
    RowComponent,
    ColumnComponent,
    TilesComponent,
    CTAComponent,
    ModalComponent,
    TextHeaderComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    TableComponent, 
    RadioComponent,
    InputComponent,
    BrandingModule,
    RowComponent,
    ColumnComponent,
    TilesComponent,
    CTAComponent,
    ModalComponent,
    TextHeaderComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Now the problem starts with the fact that there is a module thrown in there with all those components.  It's Branding Module.  Here's what Branding Module looks like:

### Branding Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from "angular2-in-memory-web-api";

import { BrandingService } from "./services/branding.service";
import { BrandingApi } from "./api/branding.api";

import { HeaderModule } from "./header/header.module";
import { FooterModule } from "./footer/footer.module";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HeaderModule,
        FooterModule,
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(BrandingApi)
    ],
    declarations: [
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderModule,
        FooterModule
    ],
    providers: [
        BrandingService
    ]
})

export class BrandingModule {

}
```

So as you can see, this module is actually importing two more nested modules, `HeaderModule`, and `FooterModule`.

Here's what those look like:

### Header Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { ButlerBarComponent } from './butler/butler.component';
import { BannerComponent } from "./banner/banner.component";
import { NavigationComponent } from "./navigation/navigation.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        ButlerBarComponent,
        BannerComponent,
        NavigationComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent,
        ButlerBarComponent,
        BannerComponent,
        NavigationComponent
    ],
    providers: []
})

export class HeaderModule {}
```

### Footer Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FooterComponent } from "./footer.component";
import { ButlerBarComponent } from './butler/butler.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from "./navigation/navigation.component";
import { LocationFinderComponent } from "./location-finder/location-finder.component";
import { SubNavigationComponent } from "./sub-navigation/sub-navigation.component";
import { DisclaimerComponent } from "./disclaimer/disclaimer.component";
import { SubFooterComponent } from "./sub-footer/sub-footer.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [
        FooterComponent,
        ButlerBarComponent,
        NavigationComponent,
        LocationFinderComponent,
        SubNavigationComponent,
        DisclaimerComponent,
        SubFooterComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        FooterComponent,
        ButlerBarComponent,
        NavigationComponent,
        LocationFinderComponent,
        SubNavigationComponent,
        DisclaimerComponent,
        SubFooterComponent
    ],
    providers: []
})

export class FooterModule {}
```

Now then, you'll see that these two modules import several of their own components and then share them upward for use in the actual `AppComponent`.  But here is where my problem resides.  I need these components that are nested two modules deep to have access to the other components imported originally in the `SharedModule`.

Technically I should be able to import `SharedModule` into the `FooterModule` and `HeaderModule` to give them access.  The problem becomes that because the `BrandingModule` itself is a part of `SharedModule` it gives the error `Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'FooterModule'`.

Is there anything I can do to get this working the way I need it to?

Answer (score 0):

That's a circular dependency:

SharedModule wants BrandingModule who wants FooterModule who wants SharedModule who wants BrandingModule who wants FooterModule... etc so nothing ever starts up

Instead of creating circles like that, why not create an helper module that these modules can all point to?